# XSLT xsl:normalize-space() function not working

Tags: xml, xslt, whitespace

I have followed the MSDN documentation verbatim [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256063.aspx) to no avail.

An example of my XML:

```
<Ticket xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <LogNo>454564</LogNo>
    <CaseNumber>
        <Part1>FGV</Part1>
        <Part2>9999</Part2>
        <Part3>88888888       </Part3>
    </CaseNumber>
</Ticket>
```

An example of my XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

 <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="/text">
  <xsl:value-of select='normalize-space()'/>
</xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Ticket">
  <Ticket><xsl:attribute name="LogNumber"><xsl:value-of select="LogNo"/></xsl:attribute>
    <CaseNumber><xsl:value-of select="CaseNumber/Part1"/>-<xsl:value-of select="CaseNumber/Part2"/>-<xsl:value-of select="CaseNumber/Part3"/></CaseNumber>
  </Ticket>
 </xsl:template>

 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

My output XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="IBM437"?>
<Tickets>
  <Ticket LogNumber="454564">
    <CaseNumber>FGV-9999-88888888       </CaseNumber>
  </Ticket>
</Tickets>
```

I am using

```
<xsl:template match="/text">
    <xsl:value-of select='normalize-space()'/>
</xsl:template>
```

as the MSDN article and everyone else on the net says, but can't seem to remove the trailing whitespace from CaseNumber Part3. Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: You have no `/text` in your input XML. Could it be you mean `text()`?

Comment: I have tried using //text(), text(), and text()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change `<xsl:template match="/text">`
to: `xsl:template match="text()">`

And use `xsl:apply-templates` instead of `xsl:value-of`.
Therefor try:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:value-of select='normalize-space()'/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Ticket">
        <Ticket>
            <xsl:attribute name="LogNumber">
                <xsl:value-of select="LogNo"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <CaseNumber>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="CaseNumber/Part1"/>-<xsl:apply-templates select="CaseNumber/Part2"/>-<xsl:apply-templates select="CaseNumber/Part3"/>
            </CaseNumber>
        </Ticket>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which will generate the following output:

```
<Ticket LogNumber="454564"><CaseNumber>FGV-9999-88888888</CaseNumber></Ticket>
```

Answer (score 7):

One way to do this is using `normalize-space` directly in the `<xsl:value-of>`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Ticket">
    <Ticket LogNumber="{LogNo}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="CaseNumber" />
    </Ticket>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="CaseNumber">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(
        normalize-space(Part1), '-',
        normalize-space(Part2), '-',
        normalize-space(Part3)
      )" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: +1 For showing another way to do things... this can make things more readable.

Comment: Yes - most prominently note the Attribute Value Template (`LogNumber="{LogNo}"`) which replaces your `<xsl:attribute ` line.

Answer (score 0):

For normalizing copy of XML-doc Y can implement next template:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
        xmlns:ns1="http://logiasoftware.fi/2010/CanonicalDataModel"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template name="NormalizeSpace">
        <xsl:element name="{name()}">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="*">
                    <xsl:for-each select="*">
                        <xsl:call-template name="NormalizeSpace"/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="*">
            <xsl:call-template name="NormalizeSpace"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought that normalize-space was not working because I was still getting line breaks in long strings.  Turns out my problem was with my xsl:output configuration.  My configuration was:

```
<xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
```

I needed to change the output method:

```
<xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
```